# How to remove V8 from CentOS 6.3?

Tags: node.js, centos, v8

nodejs crashed on startup when run with no arguments:

[root@lcnolw1073 ~]# nodejs

```
nodejs: ../src/handle_wrap.cc:65: static v8::Handle<v8::Value> node::HandleWrap::Unref(const v8::Arguments&): Assertion `args.Holder()->InternalFieldCount() > 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How to remove V8 from CentOS 6.3? 
Write commands please.

Answer (score 0):

Running `which node` will give you the absolute node path like `/path/bin/node`.

Then run `cd /path`

Once you are on the correct path do:

```
rm -r bin/node bin/node-waf include/node lib/node lib/pkgconfig/nodejs.pc share/man/man1/node.1
```

Other **alternative** is running `make uninstall`

If you instaled node to your `$HOME/local/node`, then you have to type the following command **before**:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node
```